# What does "gpg: RSA/AES256.CFB encrypted for" mean?

Tags: pgp

The output of command `fortune | gpg -vaer <receipent-id>` has a line that begins with:

```
gpg: RSA/AES256.CFB encrypted for ...
```

What is `AES256.CFB` doing here when the key is a RSA key? Isn't the data supposed to be encrypted with RSA given this is public key cryptography?

Comment: Explained in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy#Confidentiality or more technically https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.1 and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Elgamal and RSA, it's only generally possible to encrypt a small amount of data.  For ECDH and other DH variants, no data is encrypted at all; only a set of shared keys can be generated.

As a result, when we encrypt data with a public key cryptosystem, we usually use a hybrid method (called “hybrid encryption”), where the bulk of the data is encrypted with a symmetric key algorithm, and we either derive the symmetric key from a DH or ECDH approach or we derive the secret key randomly and encrypt it with the RSA or Elgamal public key.

In this case, what GnuPG is telling you is that this a hybrid of RSA for the public key and AES256 with CFB (and, presumably, the modification detection code).  You may also see “OCB” instead of “CFB” if you're using a newer version of GnuPG.  The data here is then encrypted with AES256 in the specified mode, and the symmetric key is encrypted with RSA.

Comment: It is probably worth mentioning this paradigm is called "Hybrid Encryption". Your answer includes these words separately, but it's a useful term to know to search on for things like this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In newer gpg version uses "OCB"? In version 2.4.5 I still see "CFB".

Comment: If the key has a preference for supporting AEAD, then it will say “OCB” because that will be used.  Otherwise, it will probably default to CFB.